# FirebaseInitProvider error in Signed APK, but not in debug

Tags: android, firebase, nullpointerexception, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a big problem.

I'm developing a app that uses Firebase to send Push Messages. I followed the tutorial in Google --> [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client?hl=es)

The problem comes, when I signed the APK, sudendly when the app is open, it crashed before event show anything, but this don't happen while I'm coding (app in debug)

The crash report is:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.res.Resources.getResourcePackageName(int)' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6770)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6362)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6302)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:222)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1861)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.res.Resources.getResourcePackageName(int)' on a null object reference
    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzah.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions.fromResource(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zzbu(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source)
    at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1789)
    at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1764)
    at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6767)
    ... 10 more
```

I saw in differents post here in SO, that the error happens when is not set `applicationId:xx.xx.xx` in the build.gradle file. But I have it.

So I don't know where the problems comes, I don't understant why in debug mode it works perfect, but in release mode don't. Also I have the google-services.json file in the app module.

How can I solve it?

In build.gradle file(app):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "es.in2.otr.app.im"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        multiDexEnabled true

        testApplicationId "es.in2.otr.app.im.test"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g" //specify the heap size for the dex process
    }

    lintOptions{
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }

    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}

dependencies {

    ...
    ...
    ...
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.9.0' /*Used for OKHTTP*/

    ...
    ...
    ...

    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}
```

UPDATE:

Image of google-service.json and content

[image]

```
{
  "project_info": {
    "project_number": "283882435243",
    "firebase_url": "https://XXXXX.firebaseio.com",
    "project_id": "XXXXX",
    "storage_bucket": "XXXXX.appspot.com"
  },
  "client": [
    {
      "client_info": {
        "mobilesdk_app_id": "1:XXXXX:android:XXXXX",
        "android_client_info": {
          "package_name": "es.in2.otr.app.im"
        }
      },
      "oauth_client": [
        {
          "client_id": "XXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com",
          "client_type": 1,
          "android_info": {
            "package_name": "es.in2.otr.app.im",
            "certificate_hash": "A0XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXAA"
          }
        },
        {
          "client_id": "2XXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com",
          "client_type": 3
        }
      ],
      "api_key": [
        {
          "current_key": "AIzaXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXUTM"
        }
      ],
      "services": {
        "analytics_service": {
          "status": 1
        },
        "appinvite_service": {
          "status": 2,
          "other_platform_oauth_client": [
            {
              "client_id": "XXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com",
              "client_type": 3
            }
          ]
        },
        "ads_service": {
          "status": 2
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "configuration_version": "1"
}
```

FIREBASE Console:

[image]

Comment: The [Google Services Gradle Plugin](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin) supports multiple `google-services.json` files for different build types and flavors.  Is it possible you somehow have different files for debug and release? If you have only one file, it should be in the `app/` folder at the root of your module tree.

Comment: Your `google-services.json` may need to contain both the debug and release fingerprints (SHA1 keys) for your app.  Have your entered both of them in your project settings at the Firebase console and confirmed that they are in your `google-services.json` file?

Comment: The GSG Plugin doc I linked in a previous comment explains that the result of parsing the `google-services.json` file is in `.../app/build/generated/res/google-services/{buildType}/values/values.xml`. Compare the debug and release versions to see what the differences are.

Comment: @qbix I got the file, and I think the problem is the sha1 fingerprint for release... I'll check it, and come back to tell you something. Thansk in advance

Comment: @qbix nope, didn't worked it's still launching the same error, I  updated my question with the content of JSON file, where is in the app tree, etc..

Comment: I think the structure of the JSON file is okay.  But it only contains one SHA1 fingerprint.  It should contain both the debug key and release key.  Click on "ANADIR HUELLA DIGITAL" to add whichever one is missing (debug or release) and download the new file.

Comment: Sorry for the big delay to track the question.  After all of this, I tried again to generate the json file, with the SHA1 of debug, and release. I updated the sdk, put the new version to compile of firebase-messaging -->9.4.0 . But even with all of this , it crashes with `provider.FirebaseInitProvider: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.res.Resources.getResourcePackageName(int)'`